# Issues while do_package: split_and_strip_files (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objcopy) fails

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to add lmdb to my yocto build. This is my recipe:

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=153d07ef052c4a37a8fac23bc6031972"

SRC_URI = " \
    https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/archive/LMDB_${PV}.tar.gz \
"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "0de89730b8f3f5711c2b3a4ba517b648"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "49d7b40949f2ced9bc8b23ea6a89e75471a1c9126537a8b268c318a00b84322b"

BBFILE_PRIORITY = "8"

inherit autotools-brokensep

S = "${WORKDIR}/lmdb-LMDB_${PV}/libraries/liblmdb"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    install -d ${D}${includedir}
    install -d ${D}${mandir}
    sed -i 's:\$(prefix)/man:${mandir}:' Makefile
    oe_runmake DESTDIR=${D} prefix=${prefix} manprefix=${mandir} install
}
```

It compiles fine but I get an error during do_package task:

```
ERROR: objcopy failed with exit code 256 (cmd was 'aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy' --only-keep-debug '/media/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/lmdb/0.9.16-r0/package/usr/bin/mdb_copy' '/media/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/lmdb/0.9.16-r0/package/usr/bin/.debug/mdb_copy'): aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/media/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/lmdb/0.9.16-r0/package/usr/bin/mdb_copy'
```

I tried including INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1" in my bb file. But it throws other errors:

```
ERROR: runstrip: ''aarch64-poky-linux-strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --strip-unneeded '/media/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/lmdb/0.9.16-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/liblmdb.so'' strip command failed with 1 (aarch64-poky-linux-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/media/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/lmdb/0.9.16-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/liblmdb.so'
)
ERROR: QA Issue: Architecture did not match (183 to 62) on work/aarch64-poky-linux/lmdb/0.9.16-r0/packages-split/lmdb-dev/usr/lib/liblmdb.so [arch]
WARNING: QA Issue: /usr/lib/liblmdb.so_lmdb-dev contained in package lmdb-dev requires libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit), but no providers found in its RDEPENDS [file-rdeps]
ERROR: QA Issue: Architecture did not match (183 to 62) on work/aarch64-poky-linux/lmdb/0.9.16-r0/packages-split/lmdb/usr/bin/mdb_dump [arch]
```

I'm on poky 2.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

The github link doesnt exist.

However you can skip qa packaging with

```
do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"
```